# how to get previous date files and pass ls output to array in gawk

Tags: linux, shell, awk, gawk

I have log files like below generated, and I need to daily run script ,which will list them , and then do 2 things.

1- get previous / yesterday files and transfer them to x server
2- get files older than one day and transfer them to y server

files are like below and I am trying below code but not working.

how can we pass `ls -altr` output to `gawk` ? can we built an associate array like below.

```
array[index]=ls -altr | awk '{print $6,$7,$8}'
```

code I am trying to retrieve previous date files , but not working

```
previous_dates=$(date -d "-1 days" '+-%d')


ls -altr |gawk '{if ( $7!=previous_dates ) print $9 }'

-r--------   1 root root 6291563 Jun 22 14:45 audit.log.4
-r--------   1 root root 6291619 Jun 24 09:11 audit.log.3
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root root    4096 Jun 26 03:47 ..
-r--------   1 root root 6291462 Jun 26 04:15 audit.log.2
-r--------   1 root root 6291513 Jun 27 23:05 audit.log.1
drwxr-x---.  2 root root    4096 Jun 27 23:05 .
-rw-------   1 root root 5843020 Jun 29 14:57 audit.log
```

Comment: It might be better to use something like `stat -c "%n %y"` rather than `ls`, which produces a lot of output you are not interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select files modified yesterday, you could use

```
find . -daystart -type f -mtime 1
```

and to select older files, you could use

```
find . -daystart -type f -mtime +1
```

possibly adding a `-name` test to select only files like `audit.log*`, for example. You could then use `xargs` to process the files, e.g.

```
find . -daystart -type f -mtime 1 | xargs -n 1 -I{} scp {} user@server
```

Comment: the issue with "find -mtime 1" is that ,if script is run at 8:00 am next day , it will also include files modified between 00:00 hr. until 08:00 am for same day --whereas I am looking specifically files modified between 00:00hr until 23:59 of previous day

Comment: @MohdFaisal And that is exactly why I used `-daystart`.